# Recycleview data is not updating after using notifyDataSetChanged and works on scroll

Tags: java, android, react-native

So I have a react native project here I am creating a saperate native componets for my realtime list for assetcard that are changing from firebase firstsore. But data is not updating don't know why

I tried a lot of things nothings works

```
// AssetsView.java

// Imports omitted for brevity

public class AssetsView extends LinearLayout {
    private AssetsViewAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AssetsViewModel viewModel;

    // Constructor and other methods omitted for brevity

    public void setCoinList(CoinData[] coinList) {
        viewModel.getCoinList().setValue(coinList);

        // Background thread to fetch latest data
        // Update coinList and notify adapter of data change
    }

    // Other methods omitted for brevity
}

class AssetsViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AssetsViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private CoinData[] coinList;
    // Other variables and methods omitted for brevity
}

class AssetsViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<CoinData[]> coinList;
    // Other variables and methods omitted for brevity
}
```

```
   this.coinList = coinList;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

here is my subscription code: I am updating my list on every second

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView symbol, price, name, percent;
  LinearLayout gradient;

  public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    symbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
    price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    percent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent);
    gradient = itemView.findViewById(R.id.asset_gradiant);
  }
}

  private static class RunSub {
    MutableLiveData<CoinData[]> coinList;
    AssetsViewAdapter adapter;

    RunSub(CoinData[] coinList, MutableLiveData<CoinData[]> coinListLiveData) {
      this.coinList = coinListLiveData;
      this.coinList.postValue(coinList);
      this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void run() {

      FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
      CollectionReference coinsRef = db.collection("realtime_rates_dev");

      coinsRef.addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
        Log.d("Pos:-3", "setCoinList: +" + value);
        if (error != null) {
          Log.w("FirebaseFirestore", "Listen failed.", error);
          return;
        }
        Log.d("Pos:-4", "setCoinList: +" + value);

        try {
          if (value != null && coinList.getValue().length > 0) {
            CoinData[] newCoins = new CoinData[coinList.getValue().length];
            for (int i = 0; i < coinList.getValue().length; i++) {
              newCoins[i] = coinList.getValue()[i];
              newCoins[i].setBuyRate(generateRandomFloat(0, 1000));
              newCoins[i].setName("JaaSASDSAD");
              newCoins[i].setPercentage(generateRandomFloat(0, 50));
              newCoins[i].setSymbol("sdASDSAfsdf");
            }
            coinList.setValue(newCoins);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d("Error", "run: ", e);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```